# JIRA - Use incoming emails to create tickets

Tags: communication, jira

Our team would like to use incoming emails (from Outlook) to create support tickets.

I've figured out how to successfully get this working, however, the formatting is awful.

When the ticket is created, it includes all the mail headers in the description.

What's even worse: JIRA will create a comment that contains the entire email chain every time someone replies.

The behavior that I want:

Description of the ticket = The body of the first email

Comments = The body of any email after the first

Any suggestions?

I've tried a bunch of JQL filters, but it is getting highly complicated.

Comment: "the body of any email after the first" is exactly what you're getting, since the body for the next email includes the content of all the previous ones. Welcome to the wonderful mess that is email.

Comment: @Erik It seems like JIRA should be able to detect the duplicate content on each upload though. If a user replies to an email, the extra content is just duplicate information

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, there is no practical way of doing that in Jira. After using the email-Jira integration for supporting a system for some time, we were fed up with all the long emails that include replies and also the images in screenshots that are attached to the Jira report over and over again. We gave up on email based ticket creation and started using ServiceDesk which integrates well with Jira.

Comment: We're starting to lean the same way. It is becoming too burdensome to filter out all these edge cases.

Answer (score 1):

We decided to scrap the idea of email integration altogether and migrate all JIRA requests to JIRA alone, relying on comments for discussion and the notifications to provide email alerts. This cuts our email down tremendously, and we capture more in comments than we could ever find in an email search. Plus, it makes auditing a lot easier. This may or may not work for others, but breaking the email habit is worth the effort for us.